# .htaccess how to add slash behind folder when typing it without a slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

The IfModule does fix the slash problem for all links. All links get a / behind it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

To fix the / behind folders only use and not the code above here.
Does not work in ALL browsers (IE for example).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash On
```

I was using the following code [orginal post].

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(website.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^files/$ files.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^files/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ files.php?sub=$1 [L]
```

The original link is `/files.php?sub=page1` and changes to `/files/`. This works fine.

But if I type `/files` into the url it goes to files`files/?sub=page1`.

How can I make `/files` (without the end slash) also go to `/files/` and for the folder only.

I tried a lot of things, but I can't get it right.

```
<?php
// Load pages
$sub = strtolower($_GET['sub']);
//
if(strlen($sub) > 0){
if(file_exists('files/'.$sub.'.php')){
    include('files/'.$sub.'.php');
}
    else{
        echo "<h1 class=\"titel\">Page not found.</h1>";
        echo "<p>The page doesn't exist or hasn't been found.</p>";
    }
}
else{
    include('files/page1.php');
}
?>
```

page1.php loads fine to /files/ and when using the url /files it return to files/?sub=page1
page2.php is linked like /files/page2 and shows fine.

There is only a problem with the page1 if I don't want to show page1 in the url. The url like /files/page1 works fine, but I want it like /files/

domain.com/files.php?sub=page1 loads the content fine.

domain.com/files/?sub=page1 also loads the content fine.

Comment: "The IfModule does fix the slash problem..." No, it doesn't. IfModule merely says "run this _section_ if the mod_rewrite module has been installed". The code between the `<IfModule` and the `</IfModule>` is what does the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make trailing slash optional in your rules as:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^files/$ /files.php? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^files/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /files.php?sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also important is this line `Options -MultiViews` which turns of `MultiViews` option. `MultiViews` if turned on might conflict with your rewrite rules.

Comment: I added the Multiviews and added your suggestion of /?$ but I still get the same: files/?sub=page1 I also update the topic start.

Comment: HIs files an actual directory?

Comment: These files are in a real folder yes. Anyway if I type files without the slash it does add a slash to the end (what I want), but also ?sub=page1

Comment: Ah ok, you didn't tell this fact in your question. Let me edit it

Comment: Okay, sorry :) didn't know that was important.

Comment: Have you tried this in a different browser? Also do you have any .htaccess in `/files/` directory OR an other rules in this current .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I have some extra commands. Start post updated. No other .htaccess in the folder files. Also other browsers give the same problem.

Comment: I just SOLVED the problem. Found a little piece of code... :)

Comment: Yes I just came back and detcted that your trailing slash addition rule is indeed problematic. Good to know you solved the problem.

Comment: Also now that your problem is solved you can mark the answer as "accepted" (that gives your some reps also)

Comment: It works better, but gives some other problems. It shows page hasn't been found if i try to access /files/ and /files/page2 and /files/page3 do work fine. So files/page1 also works, but only /files/ now gives an error. page1 should redirect as only one to /files/

Comment: Can you try commenting out: `RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]` rule?

Comment: Anyway the IfModule mod_rewrite.c caused to many problems for my website. I should have changed al links in the code. The code does work, but not for me. I am not going to change all links inside the code, because it adds a slash everywhere behind.

Comment: But after changing back to my default .htaccess it looks like it has been solved. I am still using the -MultiViews and DirectorySlash On. That would be the only things that have been changed in my file at the moment and it WORKS! We took a long and bumpy ride, but it has been solved. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You're most welcome, yes that trailing slash rule was indeed the cause behind this.

Comment: It only works in Opera. IE and FF still give /files.php?sub=page1 when using files without a slash behind it.

Comment: Clear your browser cache in FF

Comment: Still the same after clearing browser cache. I think it wasn't solved. Correct, if I empty the cache with Opera the problem is back. So not solved :(.

Comment: Is the problem only with `http://domain.com/files` URL? OR with any other URL also? Also do you have `DirectorySlash On`?

Comment: Yes, DirectorySlash is on. Also other urls. All the urls with /a-folder have the same problem.

Comment: No error, it shows the website correctly, but the link changes to http://domain.com/folder/?sub=includedpage

Comment: Can you open this URL in Firebug and see what you get in `Net` tab for this request.

Comment: What url must be opened in Firebug?

Comment: btw what is `includedpage` text is in this `http://domain.com/folder/?sub=includedpage` URL?

Comment: Yes, I did. The response is the same as opening /folder/. Take a look at the topic start I added the PHP code there. That shows what I mean with includedpage.

Comment: Didn't find any reference to `includedpage` in the question

Comment: includedpage was only a example/description. Tt works like this: domain.com/files.php?sub=page1 loads the content fine.

domain.com/files/?sub=page1 also loads the content fine.

Comment: I use a files.php in the public_html and inside the public_html there is a folder called /files/ inside the folder /files/ I placed all the .php pages that should load by the PHP script. Like page1.php page2.php and if(file_exists('files/'.$sub.'.php' includes the text.

Comment: I hope this makes it more understandable to you :)

Comment: yes it does help. Let me retest it locally by creating exactly same setup as yours. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Great :). If I change the DirectorySlash to Off then /files without the slash gives the response of the PHP echo "<p>The page doesn't exist or hasn't been found.</p>"; and doesn't go to files/?sub=page1 anymore. Maybe that info helps.

Comment: Hmm looks like a cache problem again. But somehow after cleaning cache it still keeps showing. Really need to test with a different browser. The DirectorySlash Off doesn't give the response I told in my post here before.

Comment: Right and `DirectorySlash Off` is never a solution or anything. It is just a hack and very unsecured.

Comment: I see. I am trying all kind of things. Been messing around with this bug for weeks. Nice learning curve. :)

Comment: Couldn't recreate the problem but I have made some edits to my answer.

Comment: ok one last update... if this doesn't work then I want you to enable `RewriteLog`

Comment: Clear browser cache and as I said enable `RewriteLog` for further debugging

Comment: Yes, I did clear browser. Doesn't work. Sorry. How do I enable Rewritelog?